# Fixing "Custom binary blocked by FRP lock" on Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime

Tags: samsung, unbricking, frp

I have Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime (SM-G610F). Because I only have 16 GB internal storage and the system takes 5 GB of space, I wanted to root my phone to remove pre-installed apps which were unimportant. Now, rooting requires the phone to be in download mode. The way you get into the Download mode is by Volume Down + Home + Power buttons, but **my Home button is faulty and doesn't work**, so I used ADB to enter Download mode. I used Odin to root my phone. While it was being rooted, there were a few disconnects from the PC. After rooting, I configured and set all the things and downloaded some important apps. Then I restarted my phone because of a few updates (personalizations). Now it is stuck at the "FRP Lock Screen" and when I hold the Power button, the phone does not boot.

The error message it displays is:

[image]

> Custom binary blocked by FRP lock

I searched on the internet for how to get out of it. I think we need to get to Recovery mode to factory reset or unroot? Usually, we can enter Recovery mode or download mode to fix FRP Lock (Factory reset or Unroot). But my Home button doesn't work on the phone, so I am not able to enter Download mode (Volume Down + Home button + Power button)  or Recovery mode (Volume up + Home button + Power Button).

I also didn't turn on Developer Options before restarting the phone, so Unlock OEM and USB debugging is off. And that's a bad thing because I could have used ADB from my computer to fix the problem. I also reset the phone three times before this problem and logged into the same Google account after each reset.

Is it possible to bring my phone back to life or is it dead?

---

*Please let me know only if I can fix this problem without spending any money. Something I could do to fix the problem and not buy anything. If there is no solution, then you can answer "NO" also.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139896/discussion-on-question-by-manan-mistry-samsung-galaxy-j7-prime-g610f-frp-lock).

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to this problem.